# Animation and transition property with setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, css

I'm fairly new to JS, and I'm trying to make a simple text slide animation. However, when the animation event is activated the first time, the transition property doesn't apply. Every time after that it works fine.

So I'm struggling with the first execution of the slide animation.

Here is the code:

```js
function slide_animation(direction){
    // Init
    let text = document.querySelector(".story .box .right-part .text");
    let text_html = text.innerHTML;
    let text_slide = [
        "Text n°1",
        'Text n°2',
        'Text n°3'
    ];
    let current_slide = 0;

    // Looking for the current_slide
    for(let i=0;i<text_slide.length;i++){
        if (text_slide[i]==text_html){current_slide = i};
    }

    // Calculating the next slide position
    if (direction=='right'){
        if (current_slide >= text_slide.length-1){
            current_slide = 0;
        }
        else {current_slide+=1;}
    }
    else {
        if (current_slide <= 0){
            current_slide = text_slide.length-1;
        }
        else {
            current_slide = current_slide-=1;
        }
    }

    // Animation
    setTimeout(()=>{
        text.style.transition = '0.5s';
        text.style.opacity = 0;
        text.style.left = '100px';  
    },250);


    setTimeout(()=>{
        text.innerHTML = text_slide[current_slide];
        text.style.opacity = 1;
        text.style.left = '0px';
    },750)
}
```

```css
.story .box .right-part .text-container .text {
    line-height: 1.25;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">  
    <div class="left-part">
        <div class="text-container">                    
            <p class="text">
                <span class="text-padding fontsize-md">----</span>
            </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="buttons-container">            
            <button class="backward" onclick="slide_animation('left')"></button>
            <button class="forward" onclick="slide_animation('right')"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="right-part">
        <div class="text-container">
            <p class="text fontsize-sm">Text n°1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway , it is fixed. I added another setTimeOut that did nothing really useful on the text , i placed it just before the others setTimeOut and it seems to work out properly.

Here is what is inserted :

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    text.style.left=0;
},0)
```